# Riddle inspired by House of Lies intro

Tags: riddle

(Inspired by House of Lies intro)

> What am I?
>   You already know what I am!
>   I'm not a executive consultant, and I'm not Marty Kaan.
>   All I have to do is make you think you don't know.
>   I'll confuse you with my words and make you think you don't know!
>   But I know you, you're better than this. So catch up!

I hope this one proves to be a little more difficult than my previous riddle, but I think someone will get it.

Comment: do you need to know anything about house of lies in order to figure this out?

Comment: No, I just worded it similar to how the main character speaks during the intro of the show :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What am I?

> A riddle.

You already know what I am!

> Because you told me in the title.

I'm not a executive consultant, and I'm not Marty Kaan.

> Riddles are not people.

All I have to do is make you think you don't know.

> Riddles are not straightforward, so you will doubt yourself.

I'll confuse you with my words and make you think you don't know!

> Riddles often have confusing language to obfuscate the answer.

But I know you, you're better than this. So catch up!

> Thanks for believing in me!

Comment: Well duh, why didn't i think of this xD genius! how do they call it again when something is hiding in plain sight?

Comment: @Ian MacDonald wish I could vote up for editing -- great job!

Comment: @dennisdeems It's the thought that counts. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're a

> Question

You already know what I am!
I'm not a executive consultant, and I'm not Marty Kaan.
All I have to do is make you think you don't know.
I'll confuse you with my words and make you think you don't know!
But I know you, you're better than this. So catch up!

> You're answering a question right now. A question makes you feel like you don't know the answer. Questions often have complex words or weird sentences. But if you're good, you can come up with a good answer to it!

Answer (score -1):

I think you are:

> doubt.

I cannot place it on a particular sentence but the overall riddle seems to be making me

> doubt

about the thing i already know. but the following stence:

> All I have to do is make you think you don't know.

> making someone think they don't know is making them doubt

same goes for the next line:

> I'll confuse you with my words and make you think you don't know!

> To further back this up the other sentences are put there as a diversion or distraction, come to think of it those (diversion/distraction) could be the answer as well xD